# Ruby - how to download a file if the url is a redirection?

Tags: ruby, http, soundcloud, response.redirect, http-redirect

Ruby how to download a file if the url is a redirection?

i'm trying to download this url:

soundcloud.com/stereo-f---/cohete-amigo/download

the redirection is this:

[ec-media.soundcloud.com/HNIGsuMJlDhy?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd0210ad0e38569b9775ddc9e06b3c362a686319250ea5c1ae2d33d8d525807641f258e33de3cb0e559c1b591b5b00fb32d5ef9&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1352919869&Signature=OVWD9VdV7ew%2B%2Fs%2BO0YpkKZLGOCw%3D][2]

and what i've tried is this:

```
Net::HTTP.start("ec-media.soundcloud.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/HNIGsuMJlDhy?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd0210ad0e38569b9775ddc9e06b3c362a686319250ea5c1ae2d33d8d525807641f258e33de3cb0e559c1b591b5b00fb32d5ef9&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&amp;Expires=1352919869&amp;Signature=OVWD9VdV7ew%2B%2Fs%2BO0YpkKZLGOCw%3D")
  open("test.wav", "wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  }
}
puts "Done."
sleep 50
```

i don't understand/know ANY of internet protocols and redirections and that things... please can give me a good explanation or help with my script to download files from soundcloud with ruby?

thankyou

**UPDATE**:

I've tried this way but i get an error:

```
Net::HTTP.start("soundcloud.com") do |http|
  resp = http.get("/dubstep-4/kill-paris-tender-love/download")

  while resp.code == '301' || resp.code == '302'
    # moved permanently or temporarily:  try again at the new location.
    resp = http.get(URI.parse(resp.header['location']))
    # ideally you should also bail if you make too many redirects.
  end

  # make sure the request was successful.
  if resp.code == '200'  
    open("test.wav", "wb"){ |file| file.write(resp.body) }
  else
    puts "Error: HTTP #{resp.code}"
  end
end
```

Error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1860:in `initialize': undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTP:0x25a9ce8> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2093:in `initialize'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1026:in `new'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1026:in `get'
        from C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/1.rb:59:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
        from C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/1.rb:48:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard library called Open URI that is higher level than Net HTTP. It follows redirects automatically:

```
require 'open-uri'
file = open("http://soundcloud.com/stereo-f---/cohete-amigo/download")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is look at `resp.code` and handle the redirect:

```
Net::HTTP.start("your.web.site") do |http|
  resp = http.get("/something")
  while resp.code == '301' || resp.code == '302'
    # moved permanently or temporarily:  try again at the new location.
    resp = http.get(URI.parse(resp.header['location']))
    # ideally you should also bail if you make too many redirects.
  end

  # make sure the request was successful.
  if resp.code == '200'  
    open("test.wav", "wb"){ |file| file.write(resp.body) }
  else
    puts "Error: HTTP #{resp.code}"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but i think i'm using your example in the wrong way, i've updated my first comment if you can help me mmore... thankyou. PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you see this guide [here](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/03/04/following-redirects-with-nethttp/) but the gist is you have to check the type of the response and then extract the URL from the body in the case of a redirection.

Now, SoundCloud probably has zaniness going on in the background with cookies and temporary URLs and such, but that's another problem to deal with.

Comment: thanks for comment, i've tried that way but my console frezzes! a lot of encrypted(i think) information printed in my console and then it freezes, iv'e used this: google = RedirectFollower.new('http://soundcloud.com/dubstep-4/kill-paris-tender-love/download').resolve