# How to download a file from URL to disk and guess filename

Tags: php, python, ruby, node.js, url

I'm looking for the right way to download a file from URL, save to disk, and figure out the filename from the URL or headers.

The solution can be in Python, Node, Ruby, or PHP - doesn't matter to me as long as one of those options.

It's easy to do a naive implementation by guessing the filename from the URL, but I need this to work even if there are redirects and the filename isn't in the URL.

Here are some example URLs and the filenames I would expect:

**Filename in URL example**

- URL: http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2010/4/14/1271276213693/Snoop-Dogg-in-2004-001.jpg
- Download should save with filename: Snoop-Dogg-in-2004-001.jpg

**Filename + Query params in URL example**

- URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9upKJ.gif
- Download should save with filename: mW7vW4j.gif

**Redirect - Filename in Header example**

- URL: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/183721111/download?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28
- Download should save with filename: I Might ft. P-Lo & K Camp.mp3

And - here's more info on the redirect case: [Ruby - how to download a file if the url is a redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385671/ruby-how-to-download-a-file-if-the-url-is-a-redirection)

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish? download a file from your own server is easy... I don't see the problem here...

Comment: guessing the filename?

Comment: @jycr753 - Added example URLs.

Comment: If the language really doesn't matter, why not use `wget` or something?

Comment: doesn't matter as long as it's one of those options :) @loganfsmyth

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but you may wish to look into using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), since [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) itself does exactly what you're asking for -- e.g. redirects.  Libcurl has [bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/bindings.html) for all of the languages you cite.

Comment: FWIW, I got the correct file name in your first and third example from `curl`, using `curl -L -O -J [url]`.  It saved the second example with URL parameters, but there is probably an option that would strip them; if not, that's a relatively easy thing to code-- strip everything including and after the question mark.  In any case, that reinforces my suggestion that [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) might be a good option to look in to.

Comment: I voted to reopen. I found it clear enough to answer after the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby, using the `Mechanize` gem, simple case:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get(url).save
```

This will even follow the redirect and save using the correct file name. It converts the http query string in the second example into a valid file name. If you want to drop any query string (warning: this can be necessary to identify a unique resource), you will have to adjust it perhaps like so:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new    
uri = URI.parse(url)    
if uri.query.nil?
  agent.get(url).save
else
  agent.get(url).save_as(File.basename(uri.path))
end
```

Comment: Example 3 (in question) saves a "download" instead of the proper name of the song :-/

Comment: With my first example it downloaded the song with the proper file name for me.

Comment: Ahh you're right! I was using the second. This is the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: FYI - here's what I used: https://api.blockspring.com/pkpp1233/download-arbitrary-file-from-url/code

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python `requests` module.

```
import requests, os

url = "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2010/4/14/1271276213693/Snoop-Dogg-in-2004-001.jpg"
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True)
realurl = resp.url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]

savepath = '' # set the folder to save to
filepath = os.path.join(savepath, realurl)

with open(filepath, 'wb') as image:
    if resp.ok:
        for content in resp.iter_content(1024):
            if content:
                image.write(content)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work in the case of a redirect or query params, right?

Comment: In the case of http://i.imgur.com/mW7vW4j.gif?go=true, it saves to filename of mW7vW4j.gif?go=true... when it should save to filename mW7vW4j.gif

Comment: Now it will save correctly. @bumpkin

Comment: I'm getting "NameError: global name 'cdn' is not defined"

Comment: Here's a redirect example though: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/183721111/download?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28

Comment: That file is hashed with the user's ID by SoundCloud. @bumpkin

Comment: Right but when you GET the URL, it returns a file with filename in the HTTP header.

Comment: What you're asking is much more complicated than what was asked for this question. Please create a new question. @bumpkin

Comment: Disagree - the point of the question was to download file and guess filename from an arbitrary URL. I was just a bit too slow to add the proper case examples. Sorry :-/.

Comment: @bumpkin zachgates has answered your question as originally asked. It is generally frowned upon to keep on revising your question, especially if someone has already answered, as your revisions invalidate the existing answer. Learn about [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) and study the various components of the response to read the headers. Parse those headers for the filename, and save the file as that.

Comment: @MattDMo very confused by your assessment. Here's a direct quote from my original question: "It's easy to do a naive implementation by guessing the filename from the URL, but I need this to work even if there are redirects and the filename isn't in the URL..."

I simply added examples since then for clarification

Comment: @bumpkin what you're asking with all these different examples is essentially impossible, unless you have different methods to parse the URL and/or response headers for each server you plan on querying. How can you tell what the filename is supposed to be if it isn't included in the headers (such as the first 2 examples)? As far as the third example is concerned, the filename is part of the `"Content-Disposition"` header, but it may not be for a different server. Some file types, like `.mp3`s, have the file name (or at least track name) embedded in the file, but many others do not.

Comment: Isn't it standard to return the filename in content disposition? Maybe not...

Comment: @bumpkin No, it's not. Nowadays, many pages are generated dynamically, and so don't actually have a filename like `index.html` or something.

Comment: Of course. But typically when you push a file from the server, like in the sound cloud example, I believe the standard is to put the filename into content disposition...

Comment: @MattDMo - check out the accepted answer. Seems to work!